# select content of div from certain offset

Tags: javascript

I'd like to select all the contents of a division from a certain height, using the height as a sort of offset. I load data from a database, put it in a div, and then get the height of the div:

```
<div id='gtheight' style='display:none;'>
<!--content is returned from database here-->
 </div>
```

i get the height of the div:

```
var heit=$(\"#gtheight\").height();
```

I have a threshold of 470px. If the content returned gives the div a height of anything more than 470px, the surplus content should be extracted, and placed in another div. So if the content gives a height of 500px, content occupying the last 40px or so (i add a surplus to the difference for appearance reasons) should be taken and placed into another 
div(500-470=30px, i add 10px to give 40px). I know i can't do this:

```
 divsaved.innerHTML=divloaded.innerHTML;//where divloaded is the variable relating
 //to the data from the db.
```

because that'll just put all the html from div1 to div2. So is there a way to do this using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the [CSS3 Regions Module](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-regions/Overview.src.html) as this seems to do exactly what you're looking for. That said, [Support is extremely lacking](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-regions) so you may want to hold off on that.

In the meantime, I'm not really sure what to suggest. It depends on if the content is text-only or if there's other elements involved. In the former case, you may be able to break the text into words and figure out where the end of the last line in the top 470px would be, but in the latter case it'd be very difficult.

Comment: both text and images are involved.I guess  i may have to find another way to achieve this.